# dismiss the keyboard on background tap, and allow delete of a list item

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to be able to tap on the background **and** the list to dismiss the keyboard (KB) using the `View` extension `hideKeyboard()`.

All works as expected, except that when I try to swipe left an item in the list of items. I cannot tap on the `delete` the item. I can fully swipe and delete the item, but I would like to be able to just tap on the red `delete` button.

So I tried to use `.simultaneousGesture`, but that does not work either. When I use `.subview`, I cannot tap on the list of items to dismiss the KB. When I use `.all`, I cannot tap to `delete`.

What can I do to have both taps functions, dismiss the KB **and** delete item action.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea().onTapGesture { hideKeyboard() }
                VStack {
                    TextEditor(text: $text)
                        .border(.red)
                        .frame(height: 100)
                    
                    ListView()
                     //   .onTapGesture { hideKeyboard() }
                      .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { hideKeyboard() }, including: .all)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @State var data = ["item-1", "item-2", "item-3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { txt in
                Text(txt)
            }
            .onDelete { index in
                if let firstIndex = index.first { data.remove(at: firstIndex) }
            }
        }.frame(height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with NavigationLinks not working when I implemented a tap anywhere to dismiss a keyboard. I got simultaneous gesture to work by applying it to an underlying view, but this is more tricky with default behavior like onDelete

Comment: Ok thanks, I followed your suggestion, and moved the `.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { hideKeyboard() }, including: .all)` to the `Text(txt)` in `ListView`.
 That gives some functionality to dismiss the KB when I tap on the `text part`
 **and** allows tapping on the `delete` button.